# unauthorized then endpoint authorization succeeded then unathorized

Tags: botframework

Curious if anyone else is experiencing problems with the botframework today?

My bot works, and then it doesn't, repeat. This is happening for all enabled channels: Facebook, Skype and Web Chat. Nothing has changed on the server end.

When I click on My Bots, and click Test, it will say: Unauthorized. Click a few more times and then it will say: Endpoint authorization succeeded. Click again and it goes back to Unauthorized.

As far as I can tell, this just started happening today and has been like this for the past four hours.

Thanks.

Comment: How was your bot created (Bot Service or SDK)?  Is your bot written in C# or node?  Where is your bot hosted?

Comment: self hosted, C# and built using the SDK. Looks like it is still an issue this morning as well.

Comment: Are your users experiencing missed messages and errors in Facebook, Skype and Web Chat?  or is it just the portal test that is failing?  (I'm trying to gather more information in an attempt to determine what is wrong.  There  were no system wide issues yesterday or today that I am aware of.)

Comment: Yes. Users are experiencing missed messages in Facebook and Skype. The errors obviously stating that the HTTP status code is Unauthorized. About 1 of 5 messages are authorized and accepted. package id="Microsoft.Bot.Builder" version="3.5.2" targetFramework="net46"

Comment: Well it seems to respond now without losing messages, but the custom Facebook custom channel list template is no longer supported or changed recently.

Comment: What do you mean by: "facebook custom channel list template"?

Comment: Using the message.channelData for custom messages. Facebook has a List Template that isn't (or wasn't) implemented in the sdk when the bot was deployed.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be completely working now. Even Facebook specific channel data is being processed by the bot. Nothing new was deployed. I'm not sure what happened. Keeping fingers crossed it continues...